# What is the simplest library for consuming wordpress xmlrpc API

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I want to consume wordpress XMLRPC API for my latest experiment. Do you know what is the simplest library to do this? PHP4 compatibility is not important as it's obsolete anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I got the answer: using WordPress's own XMLRPC processor which is based on [incutio's XMLRPC](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/) library. The file is in /wp-includes/class-IXR.php

Answer (score 2):

I won't suggest a library. I'll give you a simple curl example for a new wordpress post. To use it on your own, you may want to create a class for this stuff that there is no need to have user/pass as function parameters.

```
function wpPostXMLRPC($title, $body, $rpcurl, 
                      $username, $password, $categories=array(1))
{
   $categories = implode(",", $categories);
   $XML = "<title>$title</title>".
          "<category>$categories</category>".
   $body = "Example body text - hallo wordpress";

   $params = array('','',$username,$password,$XML,1);
   $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('blogger.newPost',$params);
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
}
```

The question is for what reason do you need a library if it is soooo easy...

The [PEAR XML-RPC package](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RPC) may be interessting for you.

Comment: The reason why I want to use library is, so that I don't have to convert wordpress's XMLRPC result back to array all by myself. I want that library do the dirty stuff!